# AS3:how to remove textfield from stage?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've a problem with actionscript 3.
On the Stage i've a texfield named "text0", when i attempt to remove it throught AS3 writing removeChild(text0), flash give me an error(Error #2025). I always used this syntax for remove MovieClip symbols, why it seems not work for textfields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can try:

```
text0.parent.removeChild(text0);
```

Comment: This is faulty, in the sense that it needs `text0` to be on the same level as the code, so the call `this.removeChild` is possible and should be used in the situation. I understand, that you want to show a different approach, but it's both redundant and wrong in code quality's terms. And it offers no better answer than just the regular `removeChild`, since it cannot possibly work this way, but not the other way around.

Comment: I agree that it's better to use this.removeChild when it's possible. As you said just want to show a different aproach in case TextField suddenly is not on main stage but in some MC by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `removeChild` on the parent of the object that is being removed.

If that isn't clear, maybe post a bit more detailed code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to remove your textfield from a container that don't have your textfield. Try tracing the parent to make sure that you are doing fine and you are targeting the right parent.

```
trace(text0.parent);
```

You can also post some code so we can help you with something particular and not just giving you theories.

Answer (score 0):

The error signals that you are trying to remove a DisplayObject with removeChild that apparently is not a child of the DisplayObjectContainer this code is executed from.

One way to solve this problem is to check if the object you are trying to remove is actually a child of the container using contains. You are doing this for some of the objects you are removing (submitButton and saveinfoButton), but not for some others.

Try wrapping the removeChild calls for txt to check whether these DisplayObjects are in the container.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the textField from its parent. If it is in a movieClip called `myMovieClip`, and your code is on the main timeline, do `myMovieClip.removeChild`

If the textField is on the main stage, then on the main timeline write `this.removeChild`

**EDIT**

If the code and textField are at the same level, then `this.removeChild`

Comment: or simply `removeChild(text0)` (`this` is unnecessary), but only if it's written inside the main document class.